# Impossible results due to property changed event being slow

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I originally wanted to post a question, how is the below situation possible in **not** multithreaded, synchronous code:

[image: Debugging screen]

But I figured the answer while writing the question: it appears, that the dividend in the equation is zero, at the time of calculation, but quickly changes value after that (note: this bug is a rare one, replicates non-deterministicly, usually when I go with arrow up/down over DataGrid).

The relevant code looks like this:

```
        public double? LeftPolyArea => Model.GetArea(LeftPolyName);
        public double? RightPolyArea => Model.GetArea(RightPolyName);
        public double? RightPolyNonOverlappingArea =>Model.GetNonOverlappingArea(RightPolyName, LeftPolyName);
        public double? ResemblenceIndex
        {
            get
            {
                if (!(LeftPolyOverlappingArea.HasValue && LeftPolyArea.HasValue && RightPolyArea.HasValue)) return null;
                var index = LeftPolyOverlappingArea.Value / ((LeftPolyArea.Value + RightPolyArea.Value) / 2) * 100;
                return Math.Round(index, 1);
            }
        }
```

and the NotifyPropertyChanged events are triggered at once:

```
public void Refresh()
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LeftPolyArea));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(RightPolyArea));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ResemblenceIndex));
        }
```

I see that had I stick to usual Notify property it would not happen, but I dont really see, why whould it not work as it is. I'd understand it if the couple of fired events changed some existing variables, which than accessed quicly would yield 'old' values, but those are get properties, so the control flow should not progress until the calculation is complete, right? What is wrong here?

[EDIT] I'm adding the model code:
[EDIT2] almost full model code:

```
public class SpatialMapsModel : ISpatialMapsModel
{
    public int RoundDigits { get; set; } = 1;

    public IOService InputOutputService { get; }

    public SpatialMapsModel(IOService ioService)
    {
        InputOutputService = ioService;
    }

    public bool IsPolygonValid(IList<C2DPoint> polygon)
    {
        return polygon?.Count > 2
    }

    public enum IntersectionType
    {
        Overlapping,
        NonOverlapping
    }

    public List<C2DHoledPolygon> GetIntersectingPolygons(IList<C2DPoint> pointsA, IList<C2DPoint> pointsB, IntersectionType whichPolygons)
    {
        var leftPoly = new C2DPolygon(pointsA.ToList(), true);
        var rightPoly = new C2DPolygon(pointsB.ToList(), true);
        rightPoly.RandomPerturb();
        var someGrid = new CGrid();
        var smallPolygons = new List<C2DHoledPolygon>();
        switch (whichPolygons)
        {
            case IntersectionType.Overlapping:
                leftPoly.GetOverlaps(rightPoly, smallPolygons, someGrid);
                break;
            case IntersectionType.NonOverlapping:
                leftPoly.GetNonOverlaps(rightPoly, smallPolygons, someGrid);
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException(nameof(whichPolygons));
        }
        return smallPolygons;
    }

    public double? GetOverlappingArea(IList<C2DPoint> pointsA, IList<C2DPoint> pointsB)
    {
        var polygons = GetIntersectingPolygons(pointsA, pointsB, IntersectionType.Overlapping);
        var area = polygons.Sum(p => p.GetArea());
        return Math.Round(area, RoundDigits);
    }

    public double? GetNonOverlappingArea(IList<C2DPoint> pointsA, IList<C2DPoint> pointsB)
    {
        var polygons = GetIntersectingPolygons(pointsA, pointsB, IntersectionType.NonOverlapping);
        var area = polygons.Sum(p => p.GetArea());
        return Math.Round(area, RoundDigits);
    }

    private Tuple<double, double, double, double> MinMax(IList<C2DPoint> input)
    {
        var minX = double.MaxValue;
        var minY = double.MaxValue;
        var maxX = double.MinValue;
        var maxY = double.MinValue;
        foreach (var t in input)
        {
            if (t.X < minX)
                minX = t.x;
            if (t.y < minY)
                minY = t.y;
            if (t.X > maxX)
                maxX = t.x;
            if (t.y > maxY)
                maxY = t.y;
        }
        return new Tuple<double, double, double, double>(minX, minY, maxX, maxY);
    }
    public void SnapToOriginInPlace(IList<C2DPoint> input)
    {
        var minXy = MinMax(input);
        for (var i = 0; i < input.Count; ++i)
        {
            input[i] = new C2DPoint(input[i].X - minXy.Item1, input[i].Y - minXy.Item2);
        }
        var poly = new C2DPolygon(input.ToList(), true);
        poly.RandomPerturb();
        var pointsCopy = new C2DPointSet();
        poly.GetPointsCopy(pointsCopy);
        for (var i = 0; i < pointsCopy.Count; ++i)
        {
            input[i] = pointsCopy[i];
        }
    }
    public KeyValuePair<string, List<C2DPoint>> GetPolygonFromFile(string fileName){...}

    public void WritePolygonToFile(IList<C2DPoint> poly, string fileName){...}

    public double? GetArea(IList<C2DPoint> points)
    {
        if (IsPolygonValid(points))
        {
            var poly = new C2DPolygon(points.ToList(), true);
            var area = poly.GetArea();
            return Math.Round(area, RoundDigits);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public double? GetPerimeter(IList<C2DPoint> points){...}
}
```

Comment: You are aware the all UI is single threaded, and property change events are not running on multiple threads?

Comment: There is no multithreading

Comment: Can we see code for `Model`?

Comment: I'll post relevant calls in a sec, though There are no bacground workers, Tasks, Threads or awaitables, if that's what you're after. Just library calls.

Comment: Very unlikely though maybe not impossible is that the maths going on is inconsistently trying to work out what your brackets are saying. Going by the values you have shown `45829.5 / ((45829.5 + 45829.5) / 2) * 100` is your equation. This is equal to `45829.5 / (45829.5) * 100` or `1 * 100`. Try changing your arithmetic to this `(45829.5 / ((45829.5 + 45829.5) / 2)) * 100` chances are there will be no difference at all, but worth a try

Comment: No no nope, no way. We would need to leave the .net ship if there were any inconsistencies in arithmetic order of operations. Though I checked anyway and it did not work.

Comment: @weston I posted the part of the model

Comment: Well there's a lot of code still missing there, so hard to say. Starting from `LeftPolyOverlappingArea`, then `C2DPolygon` etc. Does `RandomPerturb` possibly change something in original polygons which you think it changes in the copy of it?

Comment: @Arek Most of the code missing is in 3rd party library GeoLib geolib.co.uk . I added full code in the model.

Comment: Your code is different than the one before. The function `GetIntersectingPolygons` accepted polygon names as strings before, and after edit it accepts lists of points. Not possible to find a problem this way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is coming from the library that I use, GeoLib, when the X or Y value of a point are exactly equal to other X or Y, when getting overlaps. The random perturbation shall prevent that, but it's ocasionally (randomly...) not doing that, especially when scaling and transforming polygons. Hovewer it still does not answer, why would a value change during the calculation.